# mySQL syntax error while using SELECT IF(EXISTS()) in node.js client

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, upsert

I have a SQL query in node.js for my proposing system
The feature should insert data when there isn't included same data in current table.

```
    var sql= `
    SELECT IF(
        EXISTS(SELECT student_id FROM propose_${propose} WHERE student_id = '${user}'),
        (INSERT INTO propose_${propose} (student_id) VALUES ('${user}')),
        NULL
    )    
    `
    client.query(sql,(err,data)=>{
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log(data)
    })
```

as the code,query should be sent as:

```
SELECT IF(
EXISTS(SELECT student_id FROM propose_a WHERE student_id = 'account'),
(INSERT INTO propose_a (student_id) VALUES ('account')),
NULL
)
```

but it returns SQL syntex error

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',


errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO propose_a (student_id) VALUES ('account')),\n" +
    '            NULL\n' +
    "        )' at line 3",
  sqlState: '42000',
```

The problem might arose around "INSERT INTO" in the line 3 of sql query

Comment: You describe "insert when the data ***isn't*** present" but then your code logic expresses "insert when the data ***is*** present". Which do you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF()` function needs in scalar expression whereas you try to use INSERT query.

Use `INSERT .. SELECT` with according WHERE:

```sql
INSERT INTO propose_a (student_id) 
SELECT 'account'
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT student_id 
               FROM propose_a 
               WHERE student_id = 'account' )
```

Comment: Or just `INSERT INTO x(foo) SELECT DISTINCT y.foo FROM y WHERE y.foo = 'bar'`?

Comment: @MatBailie If there is more than one row in `y` which matches `WHERE y.foo = 'bar'` then your code will insert according amount of copies.

Comment: Umm, that's why there's a DISTINCT...

Comment: @MatBailie ... and performance degrade.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the `if` function of MySQL is wrong.

> IF(expression, expr_true, expr_false);

Return type of `expr_true` and `expr_false` should either be an `integer`, `float` or `string`. You're returning a mysql insert statement in `expr_true` which is syntactically wrong.

From your query, it looks like you're trying to insert into the table if the record doesn't exist. See examples of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-can-i-do-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql).